# how to convert a wikibook to e-pub or mobi?

Tags: kindle, epub, conversion, html, send-to-kindle

Not strictly a Kindle question, e-pub would work.  PDF isn't suitable.

How can I get a wikibook, in full, on my Kindle?

> Kindle support
>
> I know it's been a bit of time, but maybe it's time to add Kindle
>   support. First, mobi isn't only used by Kindle, it just happens to be
>   the most popular. Second, mobi is XHTML so the conversion from HTML to
>   mobi is actually quite simple, which is why it's the preferred
>   submission filetype for Amazon. And, the Kindle (one of the most
>   popular eReaders), also handles straight up HTML files as well, with
>   full chapter support, etc. With most older Kindles you have to change
>   the file extension to .txt or .nownow but leaving it as HTML is fine
>   and it will read it the same as it does mobi.
>
> It's just on my mind because I had such a fun time today realizing
>   that the standard book maker on the left and the supposed WS one
>   listed in Prefs/Gadgets weren't able to make epub, odt, or pdf of the
>   few books I tried. However, I should note that the epub link on the
>   left menu did work well.
>
> Anyway, I'm just thinking that we could install an already-made script
>   to handle this if any admins feel similarly. The Haz talk 05:08, 3
>   February 2014 (UTC)

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Wikisource_talk:EBook

a "book" example:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [EpubPress](https://epub.press/) to make an EPUB and then open it in [Kindle Previewer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000765261) and export it as a MOBI file.

An issue I found is that opening each page of the SQL book individually results in too many tabs for EpubPress to process. It can process the single-page version you get from one of the printable version links on the book's main page, but then the pages won't be listed individually in the EPUB's contents.